# Is lithium hydride a salt?

Tags: ionic-compounds, terminology, hydrogen

Hydrogen is generally considered a non-metal, and a non-metal and a metal often makes a salt. However, lithium hydride seems like a special case. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_hydride) does not clearly state if the compound is a salt or not, only describing it as "salt-like".

Structurally, it makes sense to classify it as a salt, due to the network structure, but are there any clear definition to settle where the compound belongs?

[image: LiH]

Comment: Many metals form hydrides; what's so special about lithium?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can hydrides be considered salts?

Comment: Salt **doesn't** mean ionic compound. And there's no purely ionic or covalent compound.

Comment: Ah! A commonly used classification may be the best way to handle this then

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article [Salt (chemistry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(chemistry)) starts off with "In chemistry, a salt is an ionic compound that results from the neutralization reaction of an acid and a base." This seems like a pretty good Chemistry 101 definition. So, in essence, this means having an anion and a cation in the salt, which further implies ionic bonding. This seems like a pretty reasonable place to start.

I'd think that the definition could be tweaked to say "a salt is a *solid* ionic compound..." That would indicate that one "molecule" isn't a salt. So one molecule of NaCl in the gas phase is a molecule, not a salt. I also have trouble thinking of molten NaCl as a salt. So I'd describe it as a "molten salt."

> Kind of like way I think German works. I'd expect that German would have some compound word for "molten salt" which better denotes that there is one new idea. So in English if a "salt" is a solid that has a 3D crystal lattice how can a salt be "molten"?

In general, there are a lot more organic salts than inorganic, so dissolving in water isn't a good restriction.

These last paragraphs point out the sorts of problem in trying to make such a definition absolutely unambiguous. You get a one sentence definition, then two pages of qualifications which render the definition useless.

I can't think of a solvent in which you could dissolve lithium hydride and I don't see how you could get lithium hydride as a neutralization reaction, so I wouldn't think of it as a salt. I don't know a better word than "salt-like" to describe such a crystal structure of anions and cations.

Comment: According to your new definition, wouldn't sodium oxide also be a salt?

Comment: Wikipedia has edited the article to meet with IUPAC's latest definition. Now, "In chemistry, a salt is a chemical compound consisting of an ionic assembly of cations and anions."

Answer (score 0):

Hydrides of metallic elements are ionic compounds. In the case of $\ce{LiH}$ there may be some covalent characters due to the small size of the $\ce{Li+}$ ion. This hydride on electrolysis in molten form gives $\ce{H2}$ on the anode, which is an indication of the presence of hydride ions and, further, this hydride reaction with water or protic acid evolves $\ce{H2}$ gas.

Comment: This answer is a bit vague. For instance, [metal carbonyl hydrides](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_carbonyl_hydride) often have particularly *non-hydridic* "hydride" ligands. When mixed with water, they may form $H_2$, but not before acting as a Lewis acid to form a more electron-rich metal complex (by displacing the carbonyl ligands with water/hydroxide ligands).

Comment: Can you give a reference for the hydrogen release? The WP article identifies these compounds as acids, and in fact hydrogen is considered as having oxidation state +1 instead of -1 in such compounds.