# Confusion regarding classification of hydrides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrogen

According to my book,hydrides are classified as Ionic/Saltlike/Saline Hydrides, Covalent/Molecular Hydrides and Metallic/Non-stochiometric/Interstitial Hydrides.

The explanation of my book is not very clear to me  I am confused that if an S-block element & Hydrogen form a covalent compound, it will be Saline or Molecular Hydride? Same question for a P-block element which forms ionic bond with Hydrogen.

I will be grateful if you would help.

Comment: Hydrides like $\ce{NaH, CaH2}$ are ionic. Compounds or ions made by hydrogen and non-metals are covalent : $\ce{B2H6, BH4^-, CH4, SiH4, NH3, PH3, AsH3, H2O, OH-, H2S, H2Te, HF, HF2^-, HCl, HBr, HI}$. Even coordinate bonds in $\ce{AlH4^- }$ are covalent. Interstitial hydrides are relatively rare, like $\ce{H2}$  dissolved into palladium.

Comment: @Maurice - those of us coming from the materials side are more familiar with interstitial hydrides, since that is how most metal hydrides (solid phases) form. Just a matter of perspective...

Answer (score 1):

Hydrides of alkaline/alkaline earth elements are *almost** always ionic because the cations are very electropositive forming a strong ionic bond. Hence, they are called *ionic*/salt like hydrides

The hydrides of p-block elements are not very strong and are non-ionic, hence they are considered *covalent* hydrides.

*The key word *almost* is because beryllium hydride is the only s-block hydride which is covalent. [$\ce{BeH2}$ is also the only known s-block hydride which can't be made by direction reaction of beryllium and hydrogen](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96533/why-cant-beryllium-react-with-hydrogen-gas-directly-to-give-hydride)  (unlike other s-block hydrides which are made by direct metal and hydrogen interaction)

Previous discussion: [Is lithium hydride a salt?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46509/is-lithium-hydride-a-salt)

Comment: But in S block, BeH2 is a covalent compound and in P block, I think GaH3 is an ionic compound. So BeH2 & GaH3 will be Saline/Saltlike or Molecular Hydrides?

Comment: @NipunKulshreshtha I was about to update on BeH2. I will update the answer. But GaH3 is unfortunately covalent. It has been detected as a transient species in the gas phase at very low temperature. However, it is stable in [its dimeric form of formula $\ce{H2Ga(H2)GaH2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digallane) which points towards its covalency and polymerism.

Comment: @NilayGhosh aww come on, what is so unfortunate about gallium hydride being covalent?

Comment: @OscarLanzi OP assumed gallium hydride was ionic/salt like :)